# Make Sublime Text use gcc4.8 on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, sublimetext2, macports

I want to use Sublime Text(2/ 3alpha) for simple c++ programs, but I cannot use c++11. I tried changing the build file, but adding -std=c++11 does not help. I do have GCC4.8 installed with macports(and it works otherwise) but apparently sublime text is using the 4.2 variant. How do I make it use the newer one? I tried googling for a solution but haven't found one so far. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the SublimeBuild file and the command line you use to invoke gcc4.8 using the terminal?

Comment: I know this isn't what you want to hear but if your on mac just use clang, the command lines tool version is wayyyyy more updated than the gcc version

Comment: `{
 "cmd": ["g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 ${file} -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
 "shell": true,
 "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",
 "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
}`

Comment: @Praetorian This is the SublimeBuild file. Hope it is good enough.

Comment: @aaronman I am happy to use clang, but I do not really now how to use the latest version. Replacing g++ with clang++ yields the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify the absolute path to your GCC 4.8 executable (since g++ is probably just a symlink to GCC 4.2 on your system).

Here's my **gcc-4.8.1 (Release).sublime-build** on Ubuntu:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/opt/gcc-4.8.1/bin/g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "-std=c++11", "-Wall", "-O3"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cxx",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that I'm passing an absolute path in 'cmd'.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Knapen suggested, the solution is to include the full path of the newer gcc. In my case, with the macports gcc, this was:

```
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.8
```

So the sublime-build looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.8", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "-std=c++11", "-Wall", "-O2"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++,
}
```